# Is SQL auth over windows auth a red flag?

Tags: authentication, compliance, sql-server, kerberos

I'm working on something where using windows authentication to SQL server is difficult if not impossible. My team member is adamant that using SQL auth is much more difficult to manage and is a major red flag from a security and compliance perspective. I can definitely see how it could be more complicated than just using the domain credentials.

I don't have a lot of experience in the world of security and compliance. I'm wondering if this is universally accepted as a non-starter or if this is maybe just his preference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, deferring to windows controller authentication is advantageous for a few reasons:

- It simplifies removing access  - how many times has someone logged into a sparsely used vendor platform and discovered that someone terminated years ago still had access? Anecdotally, I've had instances where I didn't even recognize the name of the user, as they had been terminated years before I had even been hired.
- You can build your security/access around AD group membership. Similarly to the above, this simplifies updated/maintenance and decreases the chance someone else has access to something they shouldn't.
- It lowers your overhead. Adding new users is not fun, and takes time away from other stuff you could be doing. Let the person in charge of onboarding worry about that, and then automatically piggyback off their work.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have a lot of experience in the world of security and
>   compliance. I'm wondering if this is universally accepted as a
>   non-starter or if this is maybe just his preference?

Although this might be your co-worker's preference, it is also the best practice as suggested by Microsoft. The following is from the Microsoft website:

> SQL Server has two authentication modes: Windows Authentication and
>   Mixed Mode Authentication. In Windows Authentication mode, specific
>   Windows user and groups are trusted to log in to SQL Server. Windows
>   credentials are used in the process, either via NTLM or Kerberos.
>
> It is a best practice to use only Windows logins whenever possible.
>   Using Windows logins with SQL Server achieves single sign-on and
>   simplifies login administration. Password management uses the ordinary
>   Windows password policies and password change APIs. Users, groups, and
>   passwords are managed by Windows system administrators; SQL Server
>   database administrators are only concerned with which users and groups
>   are allowed access to SQL Server and with authorization management.
>
> SQL logins should be confined to legacy applications, mostly in cases
>   where the application is purchased from a third-party vendor and the
>   authentication cannot be changed. Another use for SQL logins is with
>   cross-platform client-server applications in which the non-Windows
>   clients do not possess Windows logins. Although using SQL logins is
>   discouraged, there are security improvements for SQL logins in SQL
>   Server 2005 and later.

From a security perspective it is better to use Windows integrated authentication because in SQL Server authentication mode credentials must be transmitted over the network when the initial connection is established.

Clients often store (or cache) these credentials on the client which increases the attack surface on the client side.